# Domain Driven Design models with reference on external services

Tags: domain-driven-design

In the last few weeks, I have been studying Domain Driven Design (DDD), reading some articles, and a book. However, the company I am currently working for does not design software based on DDD principles. For some problems, I have therefore often wondered how to model them using DDD. I can understand many concepts of DDD well, but there are still some other concepts that I do not fully grasp.

One pattern that stood out to me was one that I was always unsure how to model well. Therefore, I would be very interested to know how other developers would model it. I am, of course, aware that there are different solutions to the pattern.

As I said, this is a pattern. However, I believe that to understand the point better, I can give a concrete example.

The system to be designed should manage **subscriptions** with a recurring payment. This could be a Netflix streaming subscription, for example. So there is a external system for **payments** and it's used by various other systems. The payment system got a REST Api and there is no messaging Pub/Sub infrastructure.

In my subscription domain, i want to keep track of all payments of a susbcriptions. So my subscription domain model keeps a list of **bookings** where one property is a id from the external payment system.

**Question 1:**

*Is there a better solution for the domain model?*

So if i want to add a payment for my subscription i discovered two possible workflows.

1. I first call the external payment system and get a payment id. Then I create a booking domain model and add it to the subscription.

2. I create a booking and and raise a domain event. My event handler creates a payment in the external system and updates payment id in my booking domain model.

**Question 2:**

*What is the best solution for modelling this pattern in DDD? Or is this use case not suitable for DDD?*

Thanks for your help! Ask me for any further questions.